# How can I check if a key exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Let's say I have an associative array like so: `{'key1': 22, 'key2': 42}`.

How can I check if `key1` exists in the dictionary?

Comment: In python 3 you can just use `'key1' in {'key1': 22, 'key2': 42}.keys()` refer to the `keys()` method in [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 721, accepted):

```
if key in array:
  # do something
```

Associative arrays are called dictionaries in Python and you can learn more about them in [the stdtypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: And, be sure to put the key name in quotes if it's a string.

Comment: This throws a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error for me.

Comment: how do you negate this ? if not in array ?

Comment: @astroanu `if key not in array`

Comment: Where did the word "array" come from in this answer?

Comment: @RaySalemi Not just "array". "associative array" is a different name for a dictionary.

Comment: @RafałRawicki, I mean the word 'array' in the source code. It was not initialized or described.

Comment: As accepted answers go, this one is horrible.  It in no way answers the question and is nothing more than a condescending link to the documentation.  It is sad that Google ranks this so highly.

Comment: @cstrutton Please suggest improvements. At the moment of writing this answer I didn't feel more details is necessary.

Comment: @RafałRawicki I agree that the answer is a bit sparse and that it is unfortunate that Google ranks this answer so highly.  But it isn't your fault, either.  You answered the way you thought was necessary...  Having said that, I don't think cstrutton's comment was meant for you but more on Google.

Comment: it exactly answers the question, @cstrutton...

Comment: Not entirely, Philip. Combined with Spencer Wood's comment, it fully answers the question. But I have no objection to a concise answer.

Comment: I would promote ghostdog's answer which is the closest match to the question. mydict.has_key("keyname") [Python 2.X]. if keyname in mydict for Python 3.X.

Answer (score 65):

If you want to retrieve the key's value if it exists, you can also use

```
try:
    value = a[key]
except KeyError:
    # Key is not present
    pass
```

If you want to retrieve a default value when the key does not exist, use
`value = a.get(key, default_value)`.
If you want to set the default value at the same time in case the key does not exist, use
`value = a.setdefault(key, default_value)`.

Comment: It should be noted that you should only use the `try/except` case if you expect that the key will be present approaching 100% of the time. otherwise, `if in` is prettier and more efficient. +1 for mentioning the other possibilities.

Comment: Interesting, I remember that I read somewhere in the official docs that it is better to ask for forgiveness than permission...

Comment: from point of view of performance , try/expect is better if you are dealing with dict with many keys

Answer (score 63):

Another method is `has_key()` (if still using Python 2.X):

```
>>> a={"1":"one","2":"two"}
>>> a.has_key("1")
True
```

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated, removed in python 3, and half as fast in python 2

Comment: yes it is deprecated in 2.x and yes it is half as fast in python 2.x.

Comment: deprecated applies to all new code. once it's deprecated, don't use it anymore.

Comment: the form 'key in dict' has existed since 2.2

Comment: we could go on and on about this, the fact remains, its still an alternative option for <=2.5.

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated, use `if mykey in mydict:`

Comment: **2018**: you can use `.__contains__` instead of `has_key` (available in Python [2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)) - I'm finding it useful to write one liners like `foo = mydict['foo'] if mydict.__contains__('foo') else 'bar'`

Comment: @rong even simpler you can use `foo = mydict.get('foo', 'bar')`.  The `in` operator calls `__contains__` so this is just more verbose.