# the code for counting frequency plot of letters in abody text in python

Tags: python-2.7

## I am writing a program that produce a frequency plot of the letters in a body of text. however, there is an error in my code that I can not spot it. any ideas?

```
def letter_count(word,freqs,pmarks):
for char in word:
    freqs[char]+=1
def letter_freq(fname):
fhand = open(fname)
freqs = dict()
alpha = list(string.uppercase[:26])
for let in alpha: freqs[let] = freqs.get(let,0)
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    pmarks = list(string.punctuation)
    words = [word.upper() for word in words]
    for word in words:
        letter_count(word,freqs,pmarks)                                                                                   
 fhand.close()

return freqs.values
```

Comment: Hey Alqosh. I guess you know that indents are important in python. Please use the correct indents on your code to run it or to make it understandable for further help :)

Comment: indents are not the problem (my intents are correct in my python). i get this error message:   KeyError: ' . '   i never seen it before

Comment: Well,  to understand the correct indents would be helpful for everyone who wants to help as well.

Comment: you are right. but as i said the problem is not with indents. i need to test if [char] in line 3 is punctuation mark or not, then update the freqs[char]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
freqs[char]+=1
```

with char = '.' without having initialized a value freqs['.']=0

You should check before line 3, whether the key exists already, as you can do the +=1 operation only on existing keys of the dictionary.

So something like:

```
for char in word:
    if freqs.has_key(char):
        freqs[char]+=1
```

[Python: how can I check if the key of an dictionary exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845362/python-how-can-i-check-if-the-key-of-an-dictionary-exists)

Comment: so, i should find if 'char' is a punctuation mark or not. then update freqs[char]?

Comment: Updating my answer