# saving the label into variable

Tags: variables, label, load

I load data from a csv file. When I try to save the labels column into a variable I am getting the error saying label, and the dataset was taken from https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

```
d0 = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

print(d0.head(5)) # print first five rows of d0.

# to save the labels into a variable l.
l = (d0['label'])

got output:

   pixel0  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  pixel4  pixel5  pixel6  pixel7  pixel8  \
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
3       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
4       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   

   pixel9    ...     pixel774  pixel775  pixel776  pixel777  pixel778  \
0       0    ...            0         0         0         0         0   
1       0    ...            0         0         0         0         0   
2       0    ...            0         0         0         0         0   
3       0    ...            0         0         0         0         0   
4       0    ...            0         0         0         0         0   

   pixel779  pixel780  pixel781  pixel782  pixel783  
0         0         0         0         0         0  
1         0         0         0         0         0  
2         0         0         0         0         0  
3         0         0         0         0         0  
4         0         0         0         0         0  

[5 rows x 784 columns]
```

I'm getting error

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>       ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          3077             try:
>       -> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          3079             except KeyError: 
>     KeyError: 'label'
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>            15 
>            16 # save the labels into a variable l.
>       ---> 17 l = (d0['label'])
>            18 
>            19 # Drop the label feature and store the pixel data in d.
>
> KeyError: 'label'

I cant understand the error described in anaconda

Dropped some error code as stack is showing add more detail error

Please help me on solving this problem

Comment: Are you checking for key `label` before you put it in a variable. This situation explores it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845371/1290185

Comment: I did this:          
if label in d0: 
      print("yes") 
else:
      print("no")                                 
and got "no" as output

Comment: I did this:          
if label in d0: 
      print("yes") 
else:
      print("no")                                 
and got "no" as output

I have already posted the total output in the post and it contain the label as pixel0,pixel1,...……… what do I have to do to contain all of them in "label"

and thank you for answering