Check for key in dictionary without magic value comparison
I'm using pydantic in a project to check file formatting for an object, as well as pylint for linting. Whenever I read a file with an invalid format, I want to raise an exception with a descriptive message. The code I'm using looks something like this:
# try code...
except pydantic.ValidationError as ve:
    errors = ve.errors(
        include_url=False,
        include_input=False,
        include_context=False,
    )
    messages = []
    for error in errors:
        message = f"{error['type']} at {'.'.join(str(error['loc']))}."
        if "input" in error:
            message = f"{message} Got {error['input']}"
        messages.append(message)
    message = "\n".join(messages)

And it works just fine. My problem is that
if "input" in error

is a magic value comparison. I understand why, and I know that I could do something like
VE_ERROR_INPUT_KEY = "input"
for error in errors:
    message = f"{error['type']} at {'.'.join(str(error['loc']))}."
    if VE_ERROR_INPUT_KEY in error:
        message = f"{message} Got {error['input']}"

to "solve" the problem. However, I think that creating a constant for a dict key of a third-party lib to use in a single comparison isn't good practice.
I don't want to turn magic value comparison off, since most of the time I think its good practice, but I also don't want to create a constant for one comparison. My ideal solution is to change how this check is made, but I couldn't find another way. Should I just turn the linter off for that (and other similar) lines?
Edit: I know I can tell pylint to ignore a single line. What I want to know is if there is a better way to find a key inside a dictionary that does not use a magic value comparison, or if this is how it should be done and I should tweak the rule to ignore it.
Edit 2: I'm reposting this question in codereview since I think its off topic for stack overflow.

Or you could simply try to use the key and ignore the KeyError if it doesn't exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845362/how-can-i-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-dictionary

While the duplicate is not helpful, this question is opinion-based and hence off-topic here. You're looking for a "better" way. But how would you judge whether any proposed solution is "better" than putting a # pylint: disable=... comment?

@Joooeey I don't think its opinion-based since for each error in ValidationError.errors since the point of pylint's rule is to clarify the meaning of constant values in code, and in this situation at each key in error I'd have to either add # pylint: disable, or create a constant that describes what is already clear by looking at the code. Both situations go against what the rule is trying to enforce.
However, I do agree that it's off topic since I'm not looking for an implementation or bug solution. I'm answering the question with a link to the appropriate site for the question.
